# How to get rid of padding added by WebKit when using CSS3 columns?

Tags: css, webkit

I was trying to create a two-column grid-like layout by using **[CSS3 columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)** (just for WebKit).

However, when I put some blocks into the layout, WebKit added a strange padding at the bottom of the container (click on the image to go to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashivskyy/4ndZP/)):

[image]

My very basic CSS looks like this:

```
.columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    width: 404px;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

How can I get rid of the space, so that the parent container (red) ends whith the 6th item?

What are my requirements and what I'm trying to achieve:

- `.container` **must** have a flexible height.
- `.container` **must** end **exactly** where the lowest `.item` ends.
- `.item` **must not** be broken into pieces.

---

As the first attempt, I've been trying to achieve my results using flexbox, but as the container has a flexible height, I didn't find a way to force flexbox to divide my items into two columns.

Again, my requirements:

- `.container` must have a **fixed width, flexible height**.
- `.container` should have an **exact amount of columns** (two, in this case).
- `.item`s should **wrap** automatically **into 2** (in this case) **columns**, taking **as less height as possible** (just like in column-based layout).

Starter kit:

```
.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
    flex: 0 0 50%; // 50% in this case
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: I think the behavior of column box layout (like in the demo) is normal.

Comment: Why? Why 144px free space? If I increase the height of the 6th element by 170px, it is perfectly snapped.

Comment: looks like it's not easy at all, I think you can increase the bounty upto 1000, it's worth such a bounty, however I don't think someone could solve it, your requirement is too dynamic. I have to admit that the Column-box layout is not really well implemented. If this solution can be solved, it should be something related to column box  layout, I don't think Flex-box layout can solve this (although the name ***flex*** makes us think it's very dynamic). If you just need the layout to look fine intially, here is the scripting solution http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/9bj3j/4/ , it's for fun :)

Comment: The matter is, I _really_ don't understand why there's this free space. It's illogical. If I found the source of this problem, I would probably apply some CSS hacks and it would look OK. I think I have to stick with a scripting solution for now (I can even easily calculate the desired height of a flexbox container), but this is a very interesting problem. The maximal bounty is 500, I'll increase mine to 250. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.item {
    display: block;
}
```

That change will fix it for you without using Flexbox.  You can see the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/9bj3j/.

Comment: this makes the same result with using `display:flex`, does not actually work.

Comment: I'll alter the question a little bit, no more answers like this. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
.item {
    width: 200px;
    display : flex;
}
```

Change the item style to above and it fixes the issue. Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/MiytJAk1f1104dRyLGBy?p=preview

Comment: it does not actually work, the sixth item is broken into 2 pieces, see this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/9bj3j/3/ (the 6th block is red).

Comment: `display: flex` should be on `.container`, see the bounty starter kit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to do this is with the following CSS rule:

```
.columns {
    height: 602px;
}
```

I'm not sure why it adds that extra spacing - using the developer tools, I couldn't find anything that was causing it.